# How do I make this class accept list/tuple of ints as arguments?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7, polynomials

I tried turning the variable that I get from input(which is (x,y,z) as ints) into a tuple and a list successfully, but I cant seem to get the `Polynomial()` to work with them.

```
from tkinter import *

class Polynomial:

    def __init__(self, *coefficients):
        self.coefficients = list(coefficients)

    def __repr__(self):

        return "Polynomial" + str(self.coefficients)

    def __call__(self, x):
        res = 0
        for index, coeff in enumerate(self.coefficients[::-1]):
            res += coeff * x ** index
        return res


def calculateIt():
    mathCoef = E1.get()
    botch = mathCoef
    mytuple = tuple(map(int, botch.split(',')))

    p = Polynomial(mytuple)

    for x in range(-3, 3):
       print(x, p(x))
    L1.configure(text=p)
    print(mathCoef)

window = Tk()
window.title("XImath Client 1.0")
window.configure(bg="black")
window.geometry("500x500")

L1 = Label(window, text="Input")
L1.pack()
E1 = Entry(window, bd=5)
E1.pack()

B1 = Button(window, text="go", command=calculateIt)
B1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The problem is that I want the `class(Polynomial)` to work with the variables given by user input in `mathCoef`, which is a string at first. I tried turning into a tuple successfully, but `class(Polynomial)` expects ints with this syntax - `(1, 2, 3)`. Let's say the user inputs 1,2,3 - the tuple looks exactly like this -  `(1, 2, 3)`, but when I try passing it into `Polynomial(mytuple)`, it returns:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'`

How do I turn the tuple into ints separated with commas?

Comment: Can you clarify what does not work about that code? Ideally so that people do not have to click through a GUI to find out? Please see the [mcve] page how to best help us help you.

Comment: I think you're likely going to need to give a lot more description. You haven't said what the problem is, or what your expected output is.

Comment: I changed up the post, hopefully I clarified at least a little.

Comment: Why do you create a tuple, unpack the tuple, then in the class wrap the values again and finally create a list from them, when this class could just take the tuple and work with it as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.

I believe what you may have been missing is the * in the line `p = Polynomial(*coeffs)` which tells python to unpack the list as arguments that is passes to the constructor of the class.

I've also added `repr(p)` to the line that adds the polynomial to the label, this will show you the repr string for that polynomial.

```
from tkinter import *

class Polynomial:

    def __init__(self, *coefficients):
        self.coefficients = list(coefficients)

    def __repr__(self):

        return "Polynomial" + str(self.coefficients)

    def __call__(self, x):
        res = 0
        for index, coeff in enumerate(self.coefficients[::-1]):
            res += coeff * x ** index
        return res


def calculateIt():
    mathCoef = E1.get()
    coeffs = map(int, mathCoef.split(' '))

    p = Polynomial(*coeffs)

    for x in range(-3, 3):
       print(x, p(x))
    L1.configure(text=repr(p))
    print(mathCoef)

window = Tk()
window.title("XImath Client 1.0")
window.configure(bg="black")
window.geometry("500x500")

L1 = Label(window, text="Input")
L1.pack()
E1 = Entry(window, bd=5)
E1.pack()

B1 = Button(window, text="go", command=calculateIt)
B1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```